# Usage of side by side

Tags: phrase-usage

I have some points placed on the same line, and I want to say that each side by side pair of points must be chosen to be investigated. However, the phrase "side by side" is actually adverbial, which means that I cannot use it as an adjective.

How can I explain two points that are not placed between any other points?

Comment: You can certainly use *side-by-side* like an adjective - for example, "The two pieces are side-by-side."

Comment: If the points are  in two columns with a separation in the middle, side-by-side is best.

Comment: If, on the other hand, the points are all in a row, then you could say "each consecutive pair of points".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could say **adjacent points**. The adjective [**adjacent**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/adjacent) basically means *situated next to each other*. I think this is the most common term used to describe a situation where two things are either literally touching each other or positioned in such a way that while there might be some space between them they're still physically very close to one another.